# Git - Find code changes with a specific comment in code

Tags: git

I need to find all git commits, that deleted specific comments in the code like:

```
// Revision
```

I tried `git log -S'// Revision'` but this gives me an error:
`fatal: ambiguous argument 'Revision'': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.`

Guess this needs some kind of escaping?!

Is there a way to give me a list of all commits where the search string got removed and also an easy way to see the whole diff for each commit?

Comment: Try `git log -p -S '// Revision'`, if it did'nt work, search for only the word Revison

Comment: Hi thanks :) `git log -p -G "Revision"` seems to work. -S didn't find anything and with `//` I always get the error message. Thanks!

Comment: Strange, here I don't get any errors searching using `//`. Did you use the space between the `-S` option and the string? If you don't do that it will think you want to search for `'//` in the file `Revision'`.

Comment: I think the problem was using single quotes instead of double quotes  x_X

Comment: Note: single and double quotes both work fine in Unix style shells. You're presumably using a Windows-style CLI instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `git log --diff-filter=D -p -S "// Revision"`

`--diff-filter=D`: selects only files that are removed
`-p`: Generate patch. That option gives the diff result to the search.
`-S "string"`: famous git pickaxe, search for a string in all commit files and return the commit that contain the string.
The result should be the diff for the files he found the "// Revision" string, and that string got removed.

Comment: I explained it better, so if someone has the same problem they can understand the answer.

Comment: Beware, though, that `--diff-filter=D` is not only superfluous here, but detrimental. It'll make you miss the deletion of this comment in a commit if said file is only modified. Apart from that, good answer :-)